# Op type not registered 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess' in binary running on localhost

Tags: android

I faced the error while integrating yolo custom model into android source code..

> 08-06 18:11:35.524 2934-2934/org.tensorflow.yolo E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: org.tensorflow.yolo, PID: 2934
>       org.tensorflow.TensorFlowException: Op type not registered 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess' in binary running on localhost. Make
>   sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this
>   process.
>           at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Native Method)
>           at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Graph.java:130)
>           at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Graph.java:114)
>           at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.loadGraph(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:561)
>           at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:105)
>           at org.tensorflow.yolo.TensorFlowImageRecognizer.create(TensorFlowImageRecognizer.java:42)
>           at org.tensorflow.yolo.view.ClassifierActivity.onPreviewSizeChosen(ClassifierActivity.java:55)
>           at org.tensorflow.yolo.view.CameraActivity.lambda$setFragment$0$CameraActivity(CameraActivity.java:117)
>           at org.tensorflow.yolo.view.CameraActivity$$Lambda$0.onPreviewSizeChosen(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.tensorflow.yolo.view.CameraConnectionFragment.setUpCameraOutputs(CameraConnectionFragment.java:291)
>           at org.tensorflow.yolo.view.CameraConnectionFragment.openCamera(CameraConnectionFragment.java:298)
>           at org.tensorflow.yolo.view.CameraConnectionFragment.access$000(CameraConnectionFragment.java:52)
>           at org.tensorflow.yolo.view.CameraConnectionFragment$1.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(CameraConnectionFragment.java:163)
>           at android.view.TextureView.getHardwareLayer(TextureView.java:395)
>           at android.view.TextureView.draw(TextureView.java:344)
>           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16390)
>           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17201)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3857)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3643)
>           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16382)
>           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17201)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3857)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3643)
>           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17463)
>           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16390)
>           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17201)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3857)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3643)
>           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16382)
>           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17201)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3857)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3643)
>           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16382)
>           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17201)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3857)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3643)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchDraw(DecorView.java:794)
>           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17463)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:780)
>           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16390)
>           at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:653)
>           at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:659)
>           at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:767)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3203)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2996)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2584)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1481)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7047)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:910)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:712)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:646)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:896)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6339)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:945)

Answer (score 0):

try using another version. I guess the updated versions of yolo donot support latest versions of tensorflow. I got the same error while using mobilenet_ssd_v3, I simply tried using mobilenet_ssd_v1. and issue resolved.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31309359)